# How to display text  inline BEFORE dropkick plugin dropdown

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using dropkick js plugin and Bootstrap.

Text somehow puts **AFTER** dropdown, but I need to put it **BEFORE** dropkick list

Here is example:   http://jsfiddle.net/UL4Tu/7/

Who can help me ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, what do you mean it's "adding margin below and crash view"?  I don't see anything wrong in your screenshots, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Terry, forget about 'margin and crash', I just can't put text and dropkick inline, can you help me ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UL4Tu/7/ - text is putting after, not before dropkick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my stupid question - > this is anwer - > http://jsfiddle.net/UL4Tu/8/